# 504 Gateway Time-out - Form submission on Laravel Forge server with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, laravel, forge

I am facing an error on a Laravel Forge server that has Wordpress installed when submitting forms through any form plugin.

The error is:

```
504 Gateway Time-out

nginx/1.11.9
```

The form will keep spinning and not actually submit. The head request is sent, but the server eventually times out.

It's worth noting, I have tried disabling all other plugins and themes in order to ensure it is not a plugin/theme conflict.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be easy to debug given the information you provided. I think my first step would be to increase the nginx or php timeout and see if you can get to the real issue. 

Or look through the plugin and see if it's doing anything odd. Emailing large attachments, etc.

Comment: The reason I think this should be an easy fix is - it is not just one plugin, but multiple plugins that are forms with form submissions. I have used the plugins successfully on shared servers. Turning off all plugins and switching off the theme does not resolve the issue (thus it is not a plugin/theme conflict). Therefore, it can only be something to do with nginx and Laravel forge? I cannot find any solutions, nor am I sure what to consider next.

Comment: I have discovered the data is storing in the database. Perhaps this is some kind of email sending error?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem is that you need to implement a way for emails to be sent. There are free WordPress plugins for external transactional email senders, such as SparkPost.

Once this was correctly set up, everything works as intended.

Comment: I had this problem too with a new server. No PHP errors, only the timeout error in the nginx log. It was hung up on trying to send the email 